# Align text right in li that does not have class or id

Tags: html, css

I want to align text right side. But that text does not have any id or class.

```css
.list{list-style:none;}

.list li{padding:10px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:3px;}
.list li a{color:black;}
.list li a:before {
  content: "\f00c"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px; /* same as padding-left set on li */
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">First Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Second Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Third Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Fourth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Fifth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Sixth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
</ul>
```

I want to align `Not completed` text to the right side.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the __Not completed__ in a div or span? If you do so, then you can refer to that div/span and align it to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flex` for `li` and use `justify-content:space-between;`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/631e5a9n/8/) to play-around.

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
}

.list li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list li a {
  color: black;
}

.list li a:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  /* same as padding-left set on li */
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">First Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
  <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Second Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
  <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Third Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
  <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Fourth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
  <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Fifth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
  <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Sixth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `text-align: right` css property to the parent `ul` element and then use `float: left` css property for each `a` element like this:

```css
.list{list-style:none;text-align: right;}

.list li{padding:10px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:3px;}

.list li a{color:black;float: left;}

.list li a:before {
  content: "\f00c"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px; /* same as padding-left set on li */
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">First Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Second Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Third Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Fourth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Fifth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
<li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">Sixth Lesson</a> - Not completed</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can accept only one answer as best answer which I have already selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
First wrap "Not completed" by span tag. Then add the style . I think this will solve your problem.

.list li a span {
   float: right;
}

<ul class="list">
   <li class="incomplete"><a href="http://localhost/">First Lesson</a> - <span>Not completed</span></li>
</ul>
```